# How to make Linux bridge act as a hub instead of a virtual switch?

Tags: networking, qemu, bridge

I'm using `virt-manager` and `qemu` to run virtual machines. I had a task I needed to complete that involved sniffing traffic from another VM from a Kali Linux VM. Because the bridge network acts as a switch, this was not possible (as it is in VMWare's "promiscuous mode"). I found this tutorial online: https://techglimpse.com/convert-linux-bridge-hub-vm-interospection/

This states that you can use `brctl` to change some settings of the bridge to make it act like a hub instead of a switch (and forward all frames to all hosts in the virtual network).

I ran the following commands after the bridge started, as shown in the article:

```
brctl stp virbr0 off
brctl setageing virbr0 0
brctl setfd virbr0 0
```

Then, I opened up Wireshark on Kali, with the virtual NIC in promiscuous mode. Then, in a separate VM, I ran `ping 8.8.8.8`.

When I went back to the Kali VM and attempted to view the network traffic, I could see the ICMP echo replies from 8.8.8.8, but I could not see the echo requests from the virtual machine.

I opened up a web browser on the virtual machine and navigated around, again I can only see packets destined to the VM, not packets that originated from it.

I'm guessing this is because the default gateway in the virbr0 interace is somehow being sent the packets directly, and they aren't being forwarded out to every interface.

Is there something else I can do to resolve this issue? I read about Open Vswitch, is there a way to use this or some other software to create a hub-like virtual network?

I think this may have something to do with the fact that libvirt creates separate virtual interfaces vnet* for each VM, and it doesn't make sense as to why the default gateway `192.168.122.1` would forward packets meant for the internet back onto the bridge network.

Comment: Before testing on virbr0 and libvirt's VMs (where libvirt might interact: https://libvirt.org/firewall.html ) you should test this in a separate environment in separate network namespaces. Testing with namespaces appears to work using your settings (immediate ageing and no forward delay).